# Hierarchical Model with multiple types of groups

Tags: hierarchical-bayesian

Hi I'm trying to build a model(in `pymc3`) but I'm not sure how to describe relationship I want to model.
I need a model that estimates yields in financial markets based on what cohort does a particular bond belong to, trick is that market participants divide bonds into multiple types of cohorts for example cohorts of when bonds was issued, or cohorts by whom issued the bond. The rub is that variables, when a bond was issued, and whom issued it are independent.

So I believe that my description above fits well hierarchical model except that it would need two group types to form a join distribution?

I think following describes my model well, but I'm hoping that someone can tell me if I'm even supposed to be looking at hierarchical models if so does my modification from 'vanilla' HM make sense?

$\theta$ = When bond was issued
$\omega$ = Whom issued the bond
$\alpha$ = Bond Yield

$P(\theta|D) = \frac{P(D|\theta)P(\theta)}{P(D)}$
$P(\omega|D) = \frac{P(D|\omega)P(\omega)}{P(D)}$
$P(\alpha|D) = \frac{P(D|\alpha,\theta,\omega)P(\alpha,\theta,\omega)}{P(D)}$

NOTE

I should point out that if this question seems poorly researched its because I'm thing to apply text book knowledge to a real life problem I deal with on daily basis, so I imagine there are few gaps in my knowledge that I need to fill I'm just not sure what they are yet